# Coalesce Pandas DataFrame DOWN Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coalesce

I've seen lots of solutions for coalescing columns together (left to right, etc)
But I need to do it row-wise.

| **Col A** | **Col B** | **Col C** | **Col D** | **Col E** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | NA | NA | 1 | text |
| Row 2 | NA | NA | NA | text |
| Row 3 | NA | 4 | 10 | NA |
| Row 4 | 20 | 5 | NA | text |

I want my result to be a single row that looks like...

| **Col A** | **Col B** | **Col C** | **Col D** | **Col E** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 20 | 4 | 1 | text |

I could iterate over each column, find the first non-NA entry.. then use that as the value. However, I need to do this for hundreds of thousands of distinct partitioned tables for ~30 columns. Surely there's a better solution!

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(df.bfill().head(1))
```

Prints:

```
   Col A  Col B  Col C  Col D Col E
0  Row 1   20.0    4.0    1.0  text
```